# how can I display product variation in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

Hi need help on this guys, can't find a way to do this

Main product: fruits (sku: 12345)

-variation 1: apple with image (sku: 12345-a)

-variation 2: banana with image (sku: 12345-b)

-variation 3: melon with image (sku: 12345-m)

how can I display the variation with sku:12345-b

### layout:

image + title

Comment: hi @Reigel, I just need to show the image of the variation and the title like a normal product showing on the product page and not the main product only the variation

Comment: for example: if i want to display this sku:12345-b which is a product variation of sku:12345, then that particular variation will display on the related products